# Python script doesn't work properly when ran through terminal, but works fine in Jupyter and Visual Studio

Tags: python, bash, macos, ffmpeg

I have a script to extract the audio from all video files in a folder.

The folder with videos is located at: /Users/MyName/Downloads/Video_Audio_files

When I try to run it through terminal and I'm prompted for the folder path `folder = input("Path to folder:")`, I drag and drop it there (which is how I got the above path), but the script doesn't seem to be working (stuck at 0 out of 7 and no output files).

When I input exactly the same path when prompted in Jupyter Notebook or in Visual Studio it works perfectly!

Edit: I think I have found the issue, when I drag and drop the folder, there is an extra space ('Downloads/folder ' instead of 'Downloads/folder').

```
pbar = ProgressBar()
files = []
extensions = []
folder = input("Path to folder:")
#folder = 'Video_Audio_files'
pathlist = Path(folder).glob('**/*.mp4')
for path in pathlist:
    path_in_str = str(path)
    name = path_in_str.split("/")[1]
    files.append(path_in_str.split(".")[0])
    extensions.append(path_in_str.split(".")[1])

os.system('cd ' + folder)

for i in pbar(range(len(files))):
    video_format = extensions[i]
    video_name = files[i]
    output_format = 'flac'
    output_name = video_name + '_audio'

    bashCommand = 'ffmpeg -i ' + video_name + '.'   + video_format + ' -f ' + output_format + ' -ab 192000 -vn ' + output_name + '.' + output_format
#should be of this format: bashCommand = 'ffmpeg -i Video.mp4 -f flac -ab 192000 -vn ExtractedAudio.flac'

    os.system(bashCommand)
```

Comment: On a sidenote, You really shouldn't be using `os.system` like that, especially for things like changing a directory where you take in input from the user. That can lead to a [code injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) where someone can enter `. && cat /etc/passwd`. Please consider using `os.chdir` instead

Comment: Your os.system("cd...) does not really change your working dir for the script, because.... have you guessed already?

Comment: Shouldn't the `os.system(bashCommand)` line be indented so it's part of the `for` loop above it?

Comment: @ddbug not sure what you mean. It works fine just not from the terminal. I think I have found the issue, when I drag and drop the folder, there is an extra space ('Downloads/folder ' instead of 'Downloads/folder'). Any suggestions?

Comment: call os.chdir as suggested by Edward. Then chdir will work for your script, Otherwise the change occurs somewhere outside and is thrown away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the issue as described in the edit, I just implemented the following to get rid of the extra space:

```
folder = (input("Path to folder:")[:-1])
```

Comment: To get rid of extra spaces, \n ans so on: use strip()

Comment: Did you correct `os.system('cd ' + folder)`?  That won't work because it changes the current directory of a child process, not the current one.